# Filtrar una palabra exacta en un dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Código:

```
texto = ['El', 'enfermo', 'grave', 'habla', 'de', 'trasplantes', '.']
for palabra in texto:
    filtro = data[data['palabra'].str.match(palabra, case=False )]
    print(filtro)
```

Un extracto de la respuesta que obtengo del dataframe es:

```
       palabra      tag
374         el   DA0MS0
389         el   DA0MS0
398  elementos  NCMP000
```

Lo que necesito es que solo este la palabra exacta "el" en este caso, filtrar tambien todas las palabras que contengan "el" al inicio como la palabra "elementos" en el ejemplo.

Respuesta esperada:

```
       palabra      tag
374         el   DA0MS0
389         el   DA0MS0
```

Comment: La solución fue agregando una expersión regular regex al final de la palabra a comparar: 

filtro = data[data['palabra'].str.match(palabra+ r'\b', case=False )] 
como se puede observar agregando **+r'\b'**

https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: no agregues solucionado a tu pregunta, así no funciona la plataforma; si ya tienes una respuesta agregala al espacio de respuestas y espera calificación de los demás usuarios

Comment: en tu pregunta no añadas la respuesta eso va en la parte de abajo en la zona de respuestas

Comment: Disculpa, no lo sabia, ya voy a colocar la respuesta en donde es y editar el titulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue obtenida agregando una expersión regular (regex) **+r'\b'** al final de la palabra a comparar:

```
filtro = data[data['palabra'].str.match(palabra+ r'\b', case=False )]
```

Más info: https://regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html